# Slim Twig array conversion error while rendering

Tags: twig, slim

I am just playing around with the microFramework Slim + Twig template Engine. But actually passing an array in render method.

SomeOne help me to solve the error.

running in my local environment using XAMPP

Below is my code in index.php

```
   <?php

/* Require and initialize Slim and Twig */
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
require 'Views/Twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view'              =>  new \Slim\Extras\Views\Twig(),
    'templates.path'    =>  './Templates'
));

/* Application routes */
$app->get('/', function () use($app) {
    $pageTitle = 'hello world';
    $body = 'sup world';   
    $app->render('index.php',array('title' => $pageTitle, 'body' => $body));
});

/* Run the application */
$app->run();
```

and below is the error am getting

```
    Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:
Details
Type: ErrorException
Code: 4096
Message: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Template::render() must be an array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Slim\Extras\Views\Twig.php on line 99 and defined
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Views\Twig\lib\Twig\Template.php
Line: 244
Trace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolution is an overhead. Better way is to pass `$this->all()`, which will return an array of  set's key-value data, as an argument for `$template->render()` method.

```
public function render($template)
{
    $env = $this->getEnvironment();
    $template = $env->loadTemplate($template);

    return $template->render($this->all());
}
```

Before April `$this->data` was an array but now it is a `Set` so that's why your problem occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i have to answer my question.

I have just did a little hack in the Twig.php(in slim extras) and introduced a new function called ObjectToArray and now it works

```
function objectToArray( $object ) {
            $array=array();
    foreach($object as $member=>$data)
    {
        $array[$member]=$data;
    }
    return $array;
    }
```

so my custom Twig.php files looks something like this

```
<?php
/**
 * Slim - a micro PHP 5 framework
 *
 * @author      Josh Lockhart
 * @link        http://www.slimframework.com
 * @copyright   2011 Josh Lockhart
 *
 * MIT LICENSE
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
 * a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
 * "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
 * without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
 * distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
 * permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
 * the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
 * OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
 * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
namespace Slim\Extras\Views;

/**
 * TwigView
 *
 * The TwigView is a custom View class that renders templates using the Twig
 * template language (http://www.twig-project.org/).
 *
 * Two fields that you, the developer, will need to change are:
 * - twigDirectory
 * - twigOptions
 */
class Twig extends \Slim\View
{
    /**
     * @var string The path to the Twig code directory WITHOUT the trailing slash
     */
    public static $twigDirectory = null;

    /**
     * @var array Paths to directories to attempt to load Twig template from
     */
    public static $twigTemplateDirs = array();

    /**
     * @var array The options for the Twig environment, see
     * http://www.twig-project.org/book/03-Twig-for-Developers
     */
    public static $twigOptions = array();

    /**
     * @var TwigExtension The Twig extensions you want to load
     */
    public static $twigExtensions = array();

    /**
     * @var TwigEnvironment The Twig environment for rendering templates.
     */
    private $twigEnvironment = null;

    /**
     * Get a list of template directories
     *
     * Returns an array of templates defined by self::$twigTemplateDirs, falls
     * back to Slim\View's built-in getTemplatesDirectory method.
     *
     * @return array
     **/
    private function getTemplateDirs()
    {
        if (empty(self::$twigTemplateDirs)) {
            return array($this->getTemplatesDirectory());
        }
        return self::$twigTemplateDirs;
    }

    /**
     * Render Twig Template
     *
     * This method will output the rendered template content
     *
     * @param   string $template The path to the Twig template, relative to the Twig templates directory.
     * @return  void
     */
    public function render($template)
    {
        $env = $this->getEnvironment();
        $template = $env->loadTemplate($template);
        return $template->render($this->objectToArray($this->data));
    }

    /**
     * Creates new TwigEnvironment if it doesn't already exist, and returns it.
     *
     * @return Twig_Environment
     */
    public function getEnvironment()
    {
        if (!$this->twigEnvironment) {
            // Check for Composer Package Autoloader class loading
            if (!class_exists('\Twig_Autoloader')) {
                require_once self::$twigDirectory . '/Autoloader.php';
            }

            \Twig_Autoloader::register();
            $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->getTemplateDirs());
            $this->twigEnvironment = new \Twig_Environment(
                $loader,
                self::$twigOptions
            );

            // Check for Composer Package Autoloader class loading
            if (!class_exists('\Twig_Extensions_Autoloader')) {
                $extension_autoloader = dirname(__FILE__) . '/Extension/TwigAutoloader.php';
                if (file_exists($extension_autoloader)) require_once $extension_autoloader;
            }

            if (class_exists('\Twig_Extensions_Autoloader')) {
                \Twig_Extensions_Autoloader::register();

                foreach (self::$twigExtensions as $ext) {
                    $extension = is_object($ext) ? $ext : new $ext;
                    $this->twigEnvironment->addExtension($extension);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->twigEnvironment;
    }

    /**
     * Converts PHP objects into Array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function objectToArray( $object ) {
                $array=array();
        foreach($object as $member=>$data)
        {
            $array[$member]=$data;
        }
        return $array;
        }
}
```

I think it should work without the above modification.

If you do have find any better solution , let me know

Comment: I made a slightly less significant edit to twig.php and made a pull request on it: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Extras/pull/86

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem!

```
function objectToArray($object){
    if (!is_object($object) && !is_array($object)) {
        return $object;
    }
    if (is_object($object)) {
        $object = get_object_vars($object);
    }
    return array_map('objectToArray', $object);
}
```